# WPF how to force designer to display custom window style

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls, designer

I made a new `CustomControl` based on the Window `Control`.
When I use my Control it doesn't appear in the designer mode, instead it still uses the default window style.
How can I force the designer to display my window style instead of the default one?

My MainWindow.xaml:

```
<CustomWindow:MetroWindow x:Class="Testz.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:CustomWindow="clr-namespace:MetroWindow;assembly=MetroWindow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" BorderBrush="Red">
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</CustomWindow:MetroWindow>
```

[Link to my whole project - maybe you'll need it](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=C3392940F5CF5F74!108&authkey=!AOzrwAV0_BPvtow)

How it looks in the designer and how it really looks:

[image]

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to force the designer to display the "right" window style, edited my post aswell

Comment: Are you refering to the title bar which is "grayed" in the designer and not the real window?

Comment: @Omribitan Not only, but also the actions icons are not displayed (close, maximize and minimize). If I use the design of the window directly in the app.xaml and not as custom control (which I dont want to do it because I also override functions and I need this control to be generic) - it looks ok. Do you want me to upload a picture of that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I understood what you was trying to accomplish.

The problem is that the Visual Studio Designer can't find the Resource because it is on the library. What you need to do is to create a ResourceDictionary pointing to it on you Application to be able to see the designer time template.

```
<Application x:Class="DemoMetroWindow.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MetroWindow"
             StartupUri="DemoWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:/MetroWindow;component/Themes/Generic.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

You can learn more from links bellow.

[OnApplyTemplate() never being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992993/onapplytemplate-never-being-called)

[WPF get Type in Design time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568674/wpf-get-type-in-design-time)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgalasyn/archive/2007/10/29/troubleshooting-wpf-designer-load-failures.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2007/11/08/code-behind-and-the-wpf-designer.aspx

Comment: I can't get this working. Runtime is ak, but design time shows the "normal" Window style.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Mahapps Metro, right?

You can use the styles provided by it.
[Styling a window with Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/#styling_a_window)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colours.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

You can change the color of the window by changing the Resource dictionary of Blue.xaml by other colors, just check it out.

Answer (score 0):

When the resource references in App.xaml are fine you should restart Visual Studio. In most cases the themes are then displayed correctly.

Regards